# Configure `@babel/runtime-corejs3` to exclude es.date.now

Tags: javascript, babeljs, sinon, core-js

I'm trying to prevent `@babel/preset-env` + `@babel/plugin-transform-runtime` + `@babel/runtime-corejs3` from replacing `Date.now()`, in order to work around [an issue preventing `@sinonjs/fake-timers` from working correctly](https://github.com/sinonjs/fake-timers/issues/321).

According to the [documentation for core-js](https://github.com/zloirock/core-js#ecmascript-date), there should be a way to prevent it from applying the `es.date.now` polyfill, but I cannot figure out how to apply this configuration.

## Example

### `index.js`

```
import FakeTimers from '@sinonjs/fake-timers'

FakeTimers.install()

console.log(new Date().getTime())
console.log(Date.now())
```

### Babel Transpile

```
$(npm bin)/babel index.js
...
console.log(new Date().getTime());
console.log((0, _now["default"])());
```

Note the last line of the traspilation output — I want it to be `console.log(Date.now());`

After reviewing the docs for `@babel/preset-env`, I feel like [the `exclude` option](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-env#exclude) is what I'm looking for, but I can't get it to work:

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: [
    ['@babel/preset-env', { exclude: ['es.date.now'] }]
  ],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', { corejs: 3 }]
  ]
}
```

The above gives me an error:

```
> $(npm bin)/babel index.js
{ Invariant Violation: [BABEL] ./index.js: Invalid Option: The plugins/built-ins 'es.date.now' passed to the 'exclude' option are not
    valid. Please check data/[plugin-features|built-in-features].js in babel-preset-env (While processing: "./node_modules/@babel/preset-env/lib/index.js")
...
```

*How do I configure Babel to exclude the `es.date.now` polyfill during traspilation?*

---

## Project Files

### `package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.8.4",
    "@babel/core": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.9.0",
    "@babel/register": "^7.9.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.9.2",
    "@babel/runtime-corejs3": "^7.9.2",
    "@sinonjs/fake-timers": "^6.0.1"
  }
}
```

### `babel.config.js`

```js
module.exports = {
  presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
  plugins: [
    ['@babel/plugin-transform-runtime', { corejs: 3 }]
  ]
}
```

Comment: Here's the code ready for checkout: https://github.com/fatso83/sinon-issues/blob/fake-timers-321/index.js

Comment: You can hack around the issue, of course, by confusing the stupid find-replace algorithm:
```
+const dateObj = Date;
+
 console.log(new Date().getTime());
-console.log(Date.now());
+console.log(dateObj.now());
```

Comment: I am facing the same issue and have found that if don't use plugin-transform-runtime, then it works. 
Seems like a bug with runtime plugin

Answer (score 1):

See https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/10008. plugin-transform-runtime doesn't support browser targets. plugin-transform-runtime and preset-env can work independently.

So, to summarize. Currently it's not supporteed